# Javascript converting object property to string using JSON.stringify() returning object

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

I have an array of objects, like so:

```
var arr = [{request: {funding : 123, id: 123abc, membership: true},
response: {funding : 285, success: true }},
{request: {funding : 123, id: 123def, membership: true},
response: {funding : 167, success: true }},
{request: {funding : 123, id: 123def, membership: true},
response: {funding : 234, success: true }}]
```

I am attempting to convert the nested objects into strings for a CSV parsing program however when using the following code:

```
for (var item in arr) 
    { item.response = JSON.stringify(item.response);
      item.request = JSON.stringify(item.request);
}
```

after checking `typeof(item.response)` for an item in my array, i still get returned `object`.

However, if I manually set the property of the individual item, outside a for loop, it appears to work as intended.

e.g.

```
arr[0].response = JSON.stringify(arr[0].response)
typeof(arr[0].response) // string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) the `item` is the index, and not the object itself. Instead Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), that will assign the value to `item`:

```js
var arr = [{"request":{"funding":123,"id":"123abc","membership":true},"response":{"funding":285,"success":true}},{"request":{"funding":123,"id":"123def","membership":true},"response":{"funding":167,"success":true}},{"request":{"funding":123,"id":"123def","membership":true},"response":{"funding":234,"success":true}}];

for (var item of arr) { 
    item.response = JSON.stringify(item.response);
    item.request = JSON.stringify(item.request);
}

console.log(arr);
```

If you don't want to mutate your data, [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would create a new array, with new objects, instead of changing the originals:

```js
var arr = [{"request":{"funding":123,"id":"123abc","membership":true},"response":{"funding":285,"success":true}},{"request":{"funding":123,"id":"123def","membership":true},"response":{"funding":167,"success":true}},{"request":{"funding":123,"id":"123def","membership":true},"response":{"funding":234,"success":true}}];

var result = arr.map(function(item) {
  return {
    response: JSON.stringify(item.response),
    request: JSON.stringify(item.request)
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Welcome. See the other option I've added, and don't forget to accept the answer :)